# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error - TO_DATE error?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a trigger statement where I want to compare two date values and subtract them. When I attempt to do this I get the error *ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error*

Here is the trigger code along with the insert I am attempting to do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BALANCE_FEE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON CHARTERS
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
FEE NUMBER;
ACL_DATE DATE;
EXP_DATE DATE;
GRP_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN

ACL_DATE := :NEW.ACL_RETURN_DATE;
EXP_DATE := :NEW.EXP_RETURN_DATE;
GRP_ID := :NEW.GRP_ID;


IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := (ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE) * 75;

IF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := (ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE)* -20;

ELSE
FEE := 0;
END IF;
END IF;
UPDATE CUSTOMER
     SET CUSTOMER.BALANCE = CUSTOMER.BALANCE + FEE
     WHERE CUSTOMER.GRP_ID = GRP_ID;
END;
/
SHOW ERROR;
```

Here are the insert statements I am trying to do.

```
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T001','B001',TO_DATE ('2019/01/20', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/01/20', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G002');
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T002','B002',TO_DATE ('2019/03/10', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019-03/08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G001');
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T003','B003',TO_DATE ('2019/05/05', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/05/07', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G003');
```

If it helps here is the table for charters if you think it may have something to do with that.

```
CREATE TABLE CHARTERS (
    CHARTER_ID VARCHAR(20),
    BOAT_ID VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES BOAT(BOAT_ID),
    GRP_ID VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(GRP_ID),
    EXP_RETURN_DATE DATE,
    ACL_RETURN_DATE DATE);
```

and this is the error code I get when trying to run all three insert statements

```
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T003','B003',TO_DATE ('2019/05/05', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/05/07', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G003')
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table, the data type of `GRP_ID` is `VARCHAR(20)` and in your trigger, you are assigning it to the `Number` variable.

You need to update your trigger to change the data type of the variable `GRP_ID`

Replace

```
GRP_ID     NUMBER;
```

with

```
GRP_ID     VARCHAR2(20);
```